# intersectObjects is not a function

Tags: webgl, three.js

I've been working with the Google WebGL Globe and trying to get some rudimentary interactions in place, one of which includes clicking on the bars that are generated by latitude, longitude, etc.

From what I have seen looking through loads of three.js examples, the answer lies in a projector and ray to find intersections. The problem I am running into is with the code below, which has been slightly tweaked from a couple other sources:

```
var projector = new THREE.Projector();

if (event.target == renderer.domElement) {
    var x = event.clientX;
    var y = event.clientY;
    var v = new THREE.Vector3((x/w)*2-1, -(y/h)*2+1, 0.5);
    projector.unprojectVector(v, camera);
    var ray = new THREE.Ray(camera.position, v.subSelf(camera.position).normalize());
    var intersects = ray.intersectObjects(scene.children);
    if (intersects.length > 0) {
      console.log("success");
    }
}
```

"ray.intersectObjects is not a function" is the error, specifically.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you are using an old version of the library. Update to r.52.

Comment: I thought of that as well since posting this, so I grabbed the latest one and updated my library. I'm still receiving the same error message though. I really thought that was it! =/

Comment: Ah. So you were using an old version. Your code should work with r.52 as long as `w` and `h` are defined. What is the error now?

Comment: Yeah, I was using a version from a month or two ago, but it doesn't seem to be a versioning issue as the **intersectObjects is not a function** error is still coming up. Very odd.

Comment: What is printed in the first line of the console when your program runs?

Comment: TypeError: ray.intersectObjects is not a function

var intersects = ray.intersectObjects(scene.children);

Comment: Open the three.js source file. What REVISION number is in the first few lines?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19345/discussion-between-westlangley-and-mookamafoob)

Comment: var THREE = THREE || { REVISION: '52' };

Comment: Unfortunately the chat section of the site is blocked by my employer heh.

Comment: Your code runs for me. Are you sure you are linking to the correct file? The renderer logs the REVISION number to the console upon creation in version 52.

Comment: Alright I finally got to the root of the problem with your help. It looks like the Google WebGL Globe actually uses `ThreeWebGL.js` instead of `Three.js`. I will have to figure out a way to use elements of both to get all the functionality I am looking for. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 16):

This wasn't answered... the solution is to use `new THREE.Raycaster` -- not `THREE.Ray`

Comment: Still helps out - OP should definitely mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to add scene objects in an array and try below code.

```
function onDocumentMouseDown( event ) {
            event.preventDefault();             
            var vector = new THREE.Vector3( 
                    ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1, 
                    - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1, 
                    0.5 );

                projector.unprojectVector( vector, camera );
                var ray = new THREE.Ray( camera.position, vector.subSelf( camera.position ).normalize() );

                var intersects = ray.intersectObjects( objects );                                   

                if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {              
                    console.log("success");                 
                }                          

                document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );
                document.addEventListener( 'mouseup', onDocumentMouseUp, false );
                document.addEventListener( 'mouseout', onDocumentMouseOut, false );


            mouseXOnMouseDown = event.clientX - windowHalfX;
            targetRotationOnMouseDown = targetRotation;
        }
```

Comment: Hmm, it still comes back to "intersectObjects is not a function". I don't know if it helps, but looking at the ray object in the DOM, it only appears to have the "intersectObject" and "intersectScene" methods available.